# ListView elements are not visible by default

Tags: android, android-listview

Below is my code and image. I am populating the listview with the arraylist in `runOnUIThread()` in `onpostexecute()`  which has values gotten from the remote server in the doInBackground(). But the thing is elements are visible only when the focus is on particular item. I have been trying with different things to set the elements visible, but all have gone vain. Can someone please suggest me how to get the items visible. Note: I can't extend the ListActivity, as I have another class that needs to be extended which is the subclass of an activity.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

     public void run() {
             //Updating parsed json data to Listview

            ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listsubcategory);


    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, subCategoryList);
                        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); 


                        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                        int position, long id) {



                         String selectedSubcategory = subCategoryList.get(position);
                         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on "+selectedSubcategory, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                                        }
                                });


                 }
             });
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the styling of the list items. In normal state your items have white background and white text color, therefore you can't see them. When the state changes to focused the colors change. You can easily solve the problem by using your custom list item instead of the system's `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`.

Define a layout for the item, it can be something like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/my_item_background"
    android:textColor="@color/my_text_color"
/>
```

Now, if the item's layout is `res/layout/my_list_item.xml`, create the adapter this way:

```java
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),
                                    R.layout.my_list_item, subCategoryList);
```